# Get external file title and tag info using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Having a question how can i get an external file title and tag information from properties window using VBA code?
I have tried to use this code in VBA:

```
Dim sFile As Variant
Dim oShell: Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim oDir:   Set oDir = oShell.Namespace("C:\Users\vadis\Desktop\folderis\")

For Each strFileName In oDir.Items
 For i = 0 To 134
  MsgBox (oDir.GetDetailsOf(strFileName, i))
 Next
Next
```

But it does not provide title and tag information of the file( gives only date_created and ownder info).
My file properties are here:
[image]

Comment: Works for me.  Tag information looks to be detail #18 and Title is #21

Comment: For me doesn't. Where can be a problem? I do not see any of file attribute s from #5th or #7th till the end of that loop.

Comment: Is the file location correct?

Comment: yes. the only thing it worked for me is when i used DSOFile.dll library